# Uniform uv unwrapping

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, scale

[image]

I'm having difficulty in getting a nice uniform uv unwrap. I know uv unwrapping can be a huge pain for even a skilled modeler, but if someone could help me find a way to get the unwrap to be more uniform with less stretching. The problem lies with the rim and the outer edge of the mesh what is to be a metered gauge. The circular parts are fine. I just can't get the uv to properly\evenly unwrap on the rim and outer edge. All seams are visible in the picture. I've tried placing seams in various different ways, but I'm still not getting the results I want.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't have seams along the height.

Comment: Maybe add a seam on the highest top edge loop. (And you can maybe set the 3rd dropdown property of the Image Texture node to Repeat if you find that the strip of face on the circumference of your object is to long to fit your texture.)

Comment: Apply scale and add a seam on the top

Comment: I added the seam you suggested and was able to get a uv unwrap shown in the new picture, but keep in mind i was only able to get these results by flattening the uv islands on the rim faces and the outer edge faces.

Comment: I'd probably add a seam on the side of the object, between the two outer edge loops.

Comment: Just wanted to thank all of you for your help. And i think i got it now. Instead of selecting the entire mesh and unwrapping i unwrapped the faces of both the rim and outer edge separately. The uv grid isn't perfectly uniform squares but the texture looks nice when applied. I'm about to post a new picture and if someone can. Tell me if the unwrap is acceptable or if it's possible to get a more uniform\straighter unwrap.